# How do parent classes function when one of their methods are overridden in a child?

Tags: java, inheritance

When a child class overrides multiple methods and calls a method in its parent class, does the parent class use it's own pre-defined methods, or the ones that the child has overridden?

For some context, and an example, my question stems from this question in the AP Computer Science Curriculum. Below, when `super.act()` is called, the `act` method from `Dog` calls `eat()`. Does that `eat` call go to the `eat` method in `Dog` or `UnderDdog`?

Consider the following two classes.

```
public class Dog
{
    public void act() {
        System.out.print("run");
        eat();
    }

    public void eat() {
        System.out.print("eat");
    }
}

public class UnderDog extends Dog
{
    public void act() {
        super.act();
        System.out.print("sleep");
    }

    public void eat() {
        super.eat();
        System.out.print("bark");
    }
}
```

Assume that the following declaration appears in a client program.

```
Dog fido = new UnderDog();
```

What is printed as a result of the call `fido.act()`?

1. `run eat`
2. `run eat sleep`
3. `run eat sleep bark`
4. `run eat bark sleep`
5. Nothing is printed due to infinite recursion.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways a subclass can call a superclass method:

- Call a method defined in the superclass as its own, or
- Call a method defined in the superclass specifically requesting superclass's behavior

The syntax for the first way is as follows:

```
act(); // it's the same as this.act()
```

the syntax for the second way of invocation is as follows:

```
super.act();
```

I think now you have enough information to trace what happens in your example without further help.

Comment: No, I realize that, what I want to know, is when super.act() is called, it calls eat(); does that eat call go tho the eat method in Dog or under dog? And why?

Comment: @user577829 When the `Dog` calls `eat`, it calls the one defined in the subclass, because that's an implicit `this.eat()`, and `this` is an instance of `UnderDog` with all its methods.

Comment: So even though the code is coming from Dog, it is run like it is a method defined within UnderDog?

Comment: @user577829 In Java, once a method is overridden it is overridden. You cannot call the superclass' method again unless the subclass explicitly calls `super.someMethod()`.

Comment: This is a little misleading because it implies that you can bypass calling the overriding method from another method.

Comment: Jeffrey is correct, it does not matter where the call is coming from. In fact, there is a well known OO pattern called ["Template Method"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) based on precisely this property of method overriding: the base class calls a method in a derived class to "plug in" functionality of interest into its own flow of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a method is called--either defined in the class's hierarchy or some other unrelated class--polymorphism kicks in. The target method is searched for starting from the actual class of the instance and moving up the inheritance hierarchy.

The only time this is bypassed is when calling an overridden method from the method that overrides it using `super`.